# Typescript find out stale/fresh value

Tags: typescript

I want to determine whether the value is stale or not

If the value is stale, then the type is true and vice versa

stale value is value that attached to a variable

fresh value is value that is not attached to a variable

```
const a = {a:1}

const result = IsStale(a) // IsStale is a function with generic, don't care about the runtime

type Result = typeof result // true

const result2 = IsStale({a:1})

type Result2 = typeof result2 // false
```

so what is `IsStale`? Or it is impossible?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3nAXARgL4FgBQBoksATgKYQCuANrMgJIQDKUcN5AFHAJQwEEoATwAO5GACVKtejGFiQAMxgVqdGAHoNc0lXID8xaCul0ATEhhNW7LmizYeB%20eKlqoF5C6Un3FrTCK7BDkQA)

Comment: What does a stale value mean here?

Comment: stale value is value that is attached to a variable

Comment: Are you trying to find out if a value is readonly/frozen?

Comment: I am not looking for a way to determine frozen value

Comment: Ok, if you're looking for a way to determine whether or not the provided value was a literal/directly or a variable/identifier, then I'm sorry to say you cannot do that yet.